# How do I get the h2 and h3 elements I have on the same line as my div objects?

Tags: html, css

Title says all basically. I want the text right next to the slideshow.

```
<div class="displayBorder">
    <div class="displayContainer">
        <div class="pictureContainer">
            <div class="photoContainer">
                <div class="switchPhoto" id="switchLeft-wexford" onclick="lastPhoto('wexford-1')"><</div>
                <img src="css/img/wexford-1.jpg" id="wexford-image" />
                <div class="switchPhoto" id="switchRight-wexford" onclick="nextPhoto('wexford-1')">></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <h2 id="wexford">17 My Street - Some Town, New York</h2>
      <h3>$1,249,999</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make them inline with `display: inline`?

Comment: Add display:inline-block; property and give a try.

Comment: Okay that gets them on the same line! Thanks! Now next thing, I want to move up the text so it's at the top and not at the bottom with which it looks ugly right now... @ChandraShekhar [link](https://i.gyazo.com/5067d72a3aef7c57b2187c34f9e13c0c.png)

Comment: can you fiddle CSS and HTML here?

Comment: @AndrewLi Style: https://hastebin.com/wuyilofiha.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="displayBorder">
<div class="displayContainer">
    <div class="displayTable">
        <div class="pictureContainer">
            <div class="photoContainer">
                <div class="switchPhoto" id="switchLeft-wexford" onclick="lastPhoto('wexford-1')"><</div>
                <img src="css/img/wexford-1.jpg" id="wexford-image" />
                <div class="switchPhoto" id="switchRight-wexford" onclick="nextPhoto('wexford-1')">></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="txt-con">
            <h2 id="wexford">Location</h2> <br />
            <h3>$1,249,999</h3>
            <p>Custom Built Home With Every Bell And Whistle !/ Ch Colonial With 6 Generous Bdrms, 2 Master Suites Or Use Lge Area For Office, 5 Full Baths, Wood Floors Thru-Out, Granite Eik W/               Center Isle, Top Appliances, Andersen Windows, Lots Of Details, Full Finished Basement W/ Ose, Full Wet Bar, Theater Tv Area, Playrm, Lots Of Storage, Custom Freeform Salt Pool, Custom             Pool House</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="learn-btn">LEARN MORE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

H tags have a specific purpose, to act as a header under which other content will fall. To use h tags side by side goes against their intended use (and is invalid html). The span tag does what an H tag does, but is an inline element (display:inline), where a H tag is a block level element (and acts like a div)(display:block). You can change the 'display' property of an H tag's css to do what a span does.

With that in mind, I would actually use 'display:inline-block' in your situation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        h2.asCouple {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Topic - <h2 class="asCouple">Subtopic</h2></h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `<h2>` inside `<h1>` is invalid.

Comment: I understand that this is invalid and in my answer indicated; "To use h tags side by side goes against their intended use." I have edited my answer to further qualify that this is invalid html. With that said, it does actually work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it inline when declaring the HTML element, I did something like this:

```
<h6 style="display: inline">Posted by <h4 style="display: inline">{{.}}</h4></h6>
```

By doing this, you don't change the style of all `<hSOMETHING>` elements

Answer (score 1):

@Jared Scarito is this what you need??

CSS

```
.displayContainer{
  display:table;
}

.photoContainer,.txt-con{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="displayBorder">
  <div class="displayContainer">
    <div class="pictureContainer">
      <div class="photoContainer">
        <div class="switchPhoto" id="switchLeft-wexford" onclick="lastPhoto('wexford-1')">
          <</div> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhy46.png" id="wexford-image" />
            <div class="switchPhoto" id="switchRight-wexford" onclick="nextPhoto('wexford-1')">></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="txt-con">
      <h2 id="wexford">1234 My Street - Sometown, New York</h2>
      <h3>$1,249,999</h3> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

changed the image to demonstrate

Pretty much the same HTML, added extra div around h3 and h2..

Comment: This is basically it, but why is there 4 images?

Comment: That is a single image taken from Google images just for demo

Comment: So I have a question. Why table-cell? Is there anyway we can avoid using that or is that the proper way to do so? Thanks for all your help btw. I know how annoying I can be haha.

Comment: without table-cell we need to use floats, but to align vertically we need to use padding top and bottom to the text. for some reasons we don't encourage using padding.

Comment: Okay the thing is I want the text not at the center of the image, but rather at the top of the image. I have a hidden <p> element and want to have that under the headers and be lined up right next to the img. Thanks for all your help btw

Comment: remove the vertical-align:middle property and give a try @JaredScarito

Comment: Got it working and it looks so good! Thanks so much! https://i.gyazo.com/1450a754a92a6a8e778be56e4d4271d7.png